# Cannot find declaration to go to in maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, mybatis

#### When I ran the Test Class(CountryMapperTest.java), the error has been occurred. The following is error information.

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### The error may exist in tk.mybatis.simple.mapper.CountryMapper.xml
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException:
    Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. 
    Cause: java.io.IOException: 
    Could not find resource tk.mybatis.simple.mapper.CountryMapper.xml
```

#### Project Directory

[image: Project Directory]

#### By analysing the error messages, I think that the bug comes from the following statement in the mybatis-config.xml file.

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="tk.mybatis.simple.mapper.CountryMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

#### I have tried some solutions that work for others:

1. File | Invalidate Caches / Restart
2. Select the Directory | Make Directory as Resources Root, etc..
3. Add the relative code snippet in the pom.xml:

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

#### Relative code

CountryMapperTest.java

```
package tk.mybatis.simple.mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import tk.mybatis.simple.model.Country;

public class CountryMapperTest {

    private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        try {
            Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
            System.out.println("Test1");
            sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
            System.out.println("Test2");

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelectAll() {
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            List<Country> countryList = sqlSession.selectList("selectAll");
            printCountryList(countryList);
        } finally {
            sqlSession.close();
        }
    }

    private void printCountryList(List<Country> countryList) {
        for (Country country : countryList) {
            System.out.printf("%-4d%4s%4s\n", country.getId(), country.getCountryname(), country.getCountrycode());
        }
    }
}
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
  <settings>
    <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
  </settings>

  <typeAliases>
    <package name="tk.mybatis.simple.model"/>
  </typeAliases>

  <environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
      <transactionManager type="JDBC">
        <property name="" value=""/>
      </transactionManager>
      <dataSource type="UNPOOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybatis"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="12345"/>
      </dataSource>
    </environment>
  </environments>

  <mappers>
    <mapper resource="tk.mybatis.simple.mapper.CountryMapper.xml"/>
  </mappers>
</configuration>
```

CountryMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >

<mapper namespace="tk.mybatis.simple.mapper.CountryMapper">
  <select id="selectAll" resultType="Country">
    select id,countryname,countrycode from country
  </select>
</mapper>
```

#### I expect to query the database and show data in console.

#### More Details

- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA, 2019.1
- OS: macOS Mojave, 10.14.3

Answer (score 1):

The mapper resource path should be separated by slash.

```xml
<mapper resource="tk/mybatis/simple/mapper/CountryMapper.xml"/>
```

http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers

Comment: By using slash('/') instead of dot('.'), the both also can lead to the same error.

Comment: @Sky Could you upload the project to GitHub or similar service? The directory structure is unclear from the image.

Comment: Thanks! I've sent the fix as a PR. You put the `CountryMapper.xml` in a folder named `tk.mybatis.simple.mapper`. It should be in a nested folder: `src/main/resources/tk/mybatis/simple/mapper`.

Answer (score 0):

#### In addition to the ave's solution, we also need to check the package naming and path.

Because the **optical** package naming is **the same** in IntelliJ IDEA, the both are the `tk.mybatis.simple.mapper`.

Actually, correct path is `tk/mybatis/simple/mapper`, error path is `tk.mybatis.simple.mapper`.

Please follow the below method to check it:

1. File | Project Structure...
2. click Modules | Your Project Name | Sources